# How do I “replace a function via plugins” in WordPress?

Tags: plugin-development, pluggable

I'm new to WordPress and am not understanding their docs. What I'd like to do is to replace the `wp_hash_password` (and a few other password related functions) with my own. I've already written the functions and had them tested outside WordPress to ensure functionality.

> "wp_hash_password function can be replaced via plugins. If plugins do not redefine these functions, then this will be used instead."
>
> <sup>According to WordPress docs</sup>

Unfortunately I can't find any place that tells me HOW to do it. I tried creating a PHP file in the `../wp-content/plugins/myfirstplugin/myplugin.php`. In my `myplugin.php` file I have an "overriding" function:

```
function wp_hash_password( $password ) {

 // my code is here

}
```

I also tried renaming my php file to functions.php and even used the `add_action` & `add_filter` but again the docs are less than supportive.

I have the code I just need to know how to put it in a "plugin", where the plugin goes, and how to activate the plugin (is this done in the wordpress admin's menu?)

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track with creating the plugin. All your assumptions are correct.

To avoid errors on activation you'll want to wrap the functions that you are redefining in `function_exists` blocks, as on activation those functions will already be defined:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_hash_password' ) ) :

function wp_hash_password( $password ) {
    return 'foo';
}

endif;
```

Put your code in `wp-content/plugins/myfirstplugin/myplugin.php` make sure the plugin has the [file headers](http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header) so WordPress knows it is a plugin. There is also some helpful information for this on the [Writing a plugin page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) under the heading Standard Plugin information

Then as you already assumed you activate your plugin on the plugins page in the WordPress admin.